# Laravel: Rename existing file

Tags: php, laravel

¿How can I make a rename of one file stored in:

`/resources/views/projects/{{$project->slug}}` ?

I have one form, and when I change my project->slug I want to make a rename.

Projects can be stored in two sites, in Storage::disk and in the url I put in the top of question.

To make the rename in Storage folder, I do it like this:

```
Storage::disk('projects')->move($project->slug, $request->input('slug'));
```

Comment: Any error or warning ? Move method should work.

Comment: The move method works if I use Storage::Disk but if I want to make the rename in `/resources/views/projects/{{$project->slug}}` how can I do it? @SagarGautam

Comment: you have tried to rename file with `Storage::move(file1,file2)`?

Comment: Like this? @SagarGautam           `Storage::move('/resources/views/projects/{{$project->slug}}',$request->input('slug'));`

Comment: Yes, second parameter should be the new name

Comment: Syntax is not correct, can't find the error.

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153461/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-sagar-gautam).